# Declination of the pronoun "andere"

Tags: declension

Could someone tell me the specific terminations used for declining the pronoun "andere"?

There's plenty of sites that display the terminations for the article variant of the word and none that shows how the pronoun variant is declined, which I find odd.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with declension tables like [this](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anderer)?

Comment: You can call me slow but where does it explain the declinations of the pronoun variant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two pronouns meaning 'andere/r/s': The plural form *andere* and the 
neuter *anderes*. The plural form always refers to people. Referring to things, the use of *andere* tends to be interpreted as an ellipsis [*Ich kaufe diese Schuhe nicht, ich will andere (Schuhe).*]

- nom. plur.: *Manche halten Corona für gefährlich, **andere** tun dies nicht.*
- akk. plur.: *Ich möchte auch mal **andere** sehen als immer nur meine Nachbarn.*
- dat. plur.: *Mit **anderen** spreche ich nicht über diese Geschichte.*
- gen. plur.: *Die Meinung **anderer** interessiert mich nicht.*

The neuter form is a more elevated way to say the same as *etwas anderes*:

- nom. neut.: *Er blieb bei seiner Aussage, **anderes** war aus ihm nicht
  herauszubekommen.*
- akk. neut.: *Ich hatte ehrlich gesagt im Urlaub **anderes** erwartet als diesen Dauerregen.*
- dat. neut.: *Können wir nicht auch mal von **anderem** sprechen als immer nur
  von Corona?*
- gen. neut.: ø (not possible)

The absence of the genitive neuter is the result of the fact that all possible terminations of *ander-* that one can find to mark a genitive [-(e)s; -(e)n; -(e)r] can be interpreted as nominatives or accusatives. They are not exclusive(ly?) genitive forms, hence they have to be ruled out.

As you see, the terminations are the same as the terminations of any attributive adjective placed without an article before a noun.

Even if you combine the pronoun *andere/r/s* with a determiner it is declined like an adjective:

- Seit seinem Krankenhausaufenthalt ist er **ein** völlig **anderer**.
- Erzähle bitte **den anderen** nichts davon.
- **Alles andere** besprechen wir später.

Comment: Good answer, although I don't entirely agree with the reasoning for the absence of the genitive form. "-en" cannot be interpreted as a nomative form (dative plural, however). I supposed you're right that it does result in ambiguity with the plural declension, though. That is quite interesting! It might have something to do with the way adjectival endings originated in the first place (the developed rather recently, if I recall correctly, was still quite variable in the Mhd period: http://143.50.35.73/wiki/index.php/Adjektive_im_Mittelhochdeutschen)

Comment: Of interest is that exactly the same difference in meaning is found with "alles" and "alle".